# LibreCad drawing always fills page in print preview

Tags: printing, vector-graphics, drawing, cad

I'm very new, about one day, into LibreCad, trying to make a simple drawing with two hexagrams with circles at their vertices. I started experimentally by drawing a tiny circle, whose radius I don't know where to find, but it's very small on screen. When I click Print Preview, no matter what size circle I draw, it always shows filling the whole breadth of the page.

Why is this happening, and what can I do? Also, is their no way I can show page borders in the drawing screen, so I can position my drawing elements?

Comment: It seems LibreCad print preview scales automatically the dimensions. You can check one time the _fix_ checkbox on the preview page and then, after  further modifications, it will remain fixed. So the workaround is to draw a rectangle with the size you prefer for your page, then to go to the preview page,  fix it, save the file and start to work. [Search on google](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=librecad+tutorial) for some tutorial.

Comment: @Hastur Please post that as an answer. I have to give the bounty to somebody, soon.

Comment: Ehehe... it is expiring again :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems *LibreCad print preview* scales automatically the dimensions.
You can check one time the fix checkbox on the preview page and then, after further modifications, it will remain fixed.

So a workaround is to draw a rectangle with the size you prefer for your page, then to go to the preview page, fix it, save the file and start to work...

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, the bounty expired sometime in the night, before I saw your answer. I'll post another and give it to you in 24 hours.